# gTTS como guardarlo en un PATH dentro de un bucle

Tags: python

```
def main():
    while True:
        intento=1
        archivo = input('METE EL PATH: ')
        arc_text = open(archivo,'r')
        tts = gTTS(arc_text, lang='es')
        try:
            tts.save
        except:
            while True:
                try:
                    base,ext=os.path.split(arc_text)
                    archivo=base + "(" + intento + ")" + ext
                    tts.save
                    break
                except:
                    intento+=1
                    if intento==50:
                        print("FATAL ERROR: BUCLE INFINITO")
                        exit
                        break
        else:
            print("Archivo creado con exito")
```

Estoy intentando guardar el archivo de audio pero me da error siempre. Alguna idea del error y como arreglarlo? Tambien me gustaria saber como guardarlo en un cierto PATH.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error específicamente? Y por favor incluye el aviso completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios detalles:

1. Abriste el archivo pero no lo leiste.
2. Guardas el archivo pero no indicas el nombre del archivo
3. Atrapas la excepción pero no sabes que pasa, por lo que se hace más difícil saber en qué está fallando.
4. A `os.path.split()` le estás pasando un objeto de entrada/salida, no un string ni un path

Con las correciones quedaría así

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
def main():
    archivo = input('Ingresa el archivo con la ruta completa: ')
    arc_text = open(archivo,'r')
    tts = gTTS(arc_text.read(), lang='es')
    arc_text.close()
    try:
        base, ext = os.path.split(archivo)
        if os.path.isabs(base):
            base = base+'/'
        tts.save('base'+'mp3')
    except Exception as e:
        print("EXCEPCIÓN {}".format(e))
```